# Comparing remote Git branches

Tags: git

I'm comparing remote branches, in order to see if a branch can safely be merged into Master, in order for Master to be released.

I'm doing the following:

```
git diff --name-status origin/develbranch ... origin/master
```

And I seem to get a correct list of files, like this:

```
AAAA    www/images/widget/topdown/right_dis.png
DDDD    www/includes/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/DefinitionCache/Decorator.php
```

My questions are:

1. Am I doing this correctly?
2. If I merge these branches, the DDDD file won't be deleted in Master right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, to get the diff the right way around you want to run

```
git diff --name-status origin/master ... origin/develbranch
```

That should work fine, but I'll show you some other nifty tricks:

1. `git checkout master; git branch --no-merged`

   This will show all branches that aren't fast-forwardable to master, i.e. all non-merged branches.
2. `git checkout master; git merge --no-ff --no-commit develbranch; git diff`

   This is the only way of knowing what the merge would actually look like. You can throw away the merge after you've looked at it with `git reset --hard` .
3. `git branch --contains develbranch`

   Will show all the branches that `develbranch` could be fast-forwarded to. This is useful for checking which branches all the changes of `develbranch` have been merged to.

Comment: git diff origin/master...origin/my-branch      

did not indicate changes to me, unless I git fetch first.
Is my origin remote here ignored or how can I force Git to compare remote branches?

Comment: the only way to access remote branches is via git fetch (or pull)

Comment: Would the syntax be this?
git diff --name-status origin/master..origin/develbranch